# change window left and right snap keybinding

Tags: unity, compiz

I'm trying to configure the snap functionality as how it is in Windows 7.
This means I want windows to snap left with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>, and right with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, rather than

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd>, which is how it is set in Ubuntu now.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I've tried looking in CCSM, but found the 'Grid' plugin and 'Snap' plugin, but they both seem unused (I disabled them, with no further consequences). I also took a look in keyboard shortcuts, `dconf` and `gconf`, but couldn't find any bindings out there.

I hope any one here can help me out.

Answer (score 7):

Compiz setting manager was the right track. Look into the "grid" plugin, though; the commands `put left` and `put right` are what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The commands in Compiz Settings Manager are indeed under Grid, but they are named `Left Maximize` and `Right Maximize`.